# Application vs Device - Data encrypted at rest

Tags: encryption

I have a mobile device that does not have the device's encryption settings enabled. Therefore, data stored on the device is not encrypted at rest.

I have installed an MDM containerised application on a device which uses strong methods for encrypting data in transit.

Is the data stored within this application separate to the rest of the data on the device? Is there anyway of ensuring data within an application is encrypted at rest, while the rest of the device is unencrypted (at rest)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say for certain without knowing which MDM platform you are utilizing.

I can tell you from personal experience that [Mobile Iron](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/resources/faq) containerizes and encrypts data without requiring full device encryption.

> **Does Web@Work secure cached data?**
>
> Yes. All cookies and cached data is ***encrypted*** as a part of the
> AppConnect container. This data can be wiped as a part of a selective
> wipe, should the device fall out of compliance.
>
> **How do you make sure a rogue app does not capture corporate data?**
>
> MobileIron AppConnect ***encrypts*** and stores all AppConnect Enabled (ACe)
> app data in a virtual container on the device. Rogue applications
> cannot access the data stored in the virtual container. In addition IT
> administrators can also define policy on how data is shared between
> ACe applications.
>
> **What kind of apps does AppConnect work with? HTML5, etc.**
>
> AppConnect can secure both in-house and 3rd party applications.
> Security for HTML5 app is provided by the AppConnect enabled
> Web@Worksecure browser. A complete list of AppConnect enabled 3rd
> party apps is available here. In addition to device-at-rest
> ***encryption***, AppConnect also leverages per-app VPN to secure
> data-in-transit.

Comment: Great, I think Mobile Iron is very similar to the application I am using - Good for Enterprise with the Good Dynamics platform.